# Makes integer from a pointer, makes pointer from an integer, without cast

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a function that takes in a string and returns it's reversed form:

```
char reverse_string(char* message){

char* reversed="";
assert(message!=NULL);

int last_index=strlen(message)-1;
int a;

for(a=0; a <strlen(message);a++){
    strcat(reversed, &message[last_index]);
    last_index--;
}

return reversed;
}
```

Then to call it, I did this:

```
strncpy(rev_one, reverse_string(msg_one), MAX_LENGTH);
```

the variables are declared as such:

```
char* msg_one;
char* msg_two;
char* rev_one;
char* rev_two;
```

I'm basically reversing a string and then storing it into another string. I don't get any other errors except:

```
 ../display.c: In function 'reverse_string':
 ../display.c:38: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
 ../display.c: In function 'string_init':
 ../display.c:45: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strncpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
 ../display.c:46: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strncpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

I read on another post that the function shouldn't have a `return` statement unless it allocates the variable passed but mine stores the reversed string in another variable. Is removing the `return` statement a good idea? and how would I go about fixing this issue, I'd appreciate the help, thanks!

Update:
I read over all the comments and this is my final code, I tried memory allocation and fixing the return type, the code returns no errors but I want to make sure it's good, I'd appreciate some feedback on it:

```
char* reverse_string(char* message){

assert(message!=NULL);
char* reversed=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

if (reversed == 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
    }


int last_index=strlen(message)-1;
int a;

for(a=0; a <strlen(message);a++){
    strcat(reversed, &message[last_index]);
    last_index--;
}

return reversed;
}
```

I wanted to allocate memory ass `reversed[MAX_LENGTH]` where `#define MAX_LENGTH 20` but I kept getting an error saying "function returns address of local variable" so I used `malloc` instead although I have only basic knowledge on it.

UPDATE 2
Okay so I updated the last code and fixed the memory alloc size based on the suggestions

I also took some notes from one of the comments below and made another quick method

```
char* reverse_string_into(char* reversed, char* message){
assert(message!=NULL);

const size_t len = strlen(message);
const size_t last = len - 1;

int i;
for (i=0; i<len; i++){
    reversed[i] = message[last - i];
}
return NULL;
}
```

Could it work? am I back on the issue of memory?

Comment: Must be `char *reverse_string`, not `char reverse_string`.

Comment: `reversed` is a pointer pointing to `""` (a constant string stored with 1 byte (the silent `\0` for end)). `strcat()` stores the concatenation of `reversed` and `&message[last_index]`. Bang! There is no memory allocated to store the result of [`strcat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/). Please, read the manual I linked for `strcat()`. Remark: The compiler might compile allocation of extra bytes for `""` (e.g. for alignment or whatever). May be the crash happens not in first iteration but later. This makes it even more worse.

Comment: I will go over the documentation for `strcat()`. I guess I was still using a sort of Java/Python mindset, my bad

Comment: `reversed`points to a string literal; it is UB to modify a string literal, as you do with `strcat()`.

Comment: When you declared `reversed[MAX_LENGTH]`, it was an automatic variable with a lifetime that ends when the function terminates. By using `malloc()` you allocate memory and assign the address to a pointer; the value of that pointer is returned to the calling function, and the memory remains allocated.

Comment: malloc(sizeof(char)) should be malloc((strlen(message)+1) * sizeof(char));

Comment: In your program, you should make sure you free the memory allocated using malloc, when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Note that you only allocate space for one `char`, where you need to allocate space for `strlen(message) + 1` `char`s: `char* reversed = malloc(strlen(message) + 1);`. There is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` in C, and `sizeof char` is always 1.

Comment: @Jay, yes I plan on freeing it after the `strncpy()` is done

Comment: @DavidBowling Thank you, I'll change the malloc size now. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Warnings are caused due to the below problem in your code:*

The below prototype is incorrect as your intention is to return `char *` and not `char`

```
 char reverse_string(char* message)
```

It should be

```
char *reverse_string(char* message)
```

---

*Below problem is not causing your warnings, but, nevertheless, this problem exists in your code*:

Also, in the function reverse_string, you should be allocating memory and point it to `reversed`. Currently, there is no memory allocated to `reversed` and when you do a `strcat`, it will result in writing into memory which you do not own and can result in undefined behavior. There must be enough memory in the destination string passed to strcat to hold the result (concatenated string). Please refer to man page of strcat about it's usage.

Answer (score 0):

Messages are pretty clear:

1. `return reversed` returns an address (pointer value) but the return type is `char`, change it to `char *`
2. This will immediately disappear if you make the previous editing, as the `reverse_string` function is declared to return a `char` your `strncpy` your usage is wrong: the second argument must be an address.

Remains some more problems: allocation for `reverse`, your algorithm for reversing is weird,...

Comment: For the algorithm, I tried copying "message" into reversed in reverse order. What's weird about it? is it just the way I tried to do it or the implementation?

Comment: If the second argument is meant to be an address,how do I go bout modifying the code? Would it be wise to make a global variable, modify it in `reverse_string` and then pass the address of that variable to `strncpy`? or just pass the returned variable of `reverse_string` to a variable and pass the address of that to `strncpy`?

Comment: I told you: correcting the first will correct the second.

Comment: yes I tried it and you were right, thanks....sorry, I guess I didn't read your answer right

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues:

1. The function `reverse_string`'s signature has it returning a `char` instead of a `char*`. This is why you're getting your line 38 warning.
2. In the function `reverse_string`, you're trying to use a single character string to store all the data from `strcat` and then you're trying to return this memory.
3. In the function `reverse_string`, you're repeatedly calling `strlen` in your `for` loop. `strlen` works by iterating over its given char pointer until it finds the null character and then returning how many characters it saw. If you call `strlen` just prior to your loop, cache its result, and then instead use that cached result in the loop, then you can be certain that your code isn't wasting cycles recomputing the length on every iteration of your loop.
4. Since your `reverse_string` function returns a `char` and `strncpy` is expecting a pointer to a `char` the compiler is warning you that it's doing what you've asked it to do by making a pointer from an integer (which the `char` is promoted to).
5. `malloc` allocates the number of bytes of memory that it's asked to allocate. Calling it with `sizeof(char)` will allocate 1 byte. If you're going to copy more than that amount of data however, then you'll need a to allocate as much memory as all of the data you'll be copying including the null terminating character. So you'd need to call `malloc` with `strlen(message) + 1` or more, as the size to allocate. Otherwise your code may corrupt memory.

Here's an example of what reversing functions could look like and how to use them (this is not meant to be perfect code but simply compilable and usable):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Reverses a null terminated character array in place.
 * Note that the memory pointed at by the "string" parameter must
 * really be writable. I.e. you can't pass this a string stored in ROM.
 */
char* reverse_string_inplace(char* string)
{
    const size_t len = strlen(string);
    const size_t last = len - 1;
    const size_t mid = len / 2;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        char tmp = string[i];
        string[i] = string[last - i];
        string[last - i] = tmp;
    }
    return string;
}

char* reverse_strncpy(char *dst, const char* src, size_t dstsiz)
{
    if (dst != NULL && dstsiz > 0)
    {
        const size_t len = strlen(src);
        const size_t last = len - 1;
        size_t i = 0;

        if (dstsiz > len)
        {
            for (; i < len; i++)
            {
                dst[i] = src[last - i];
            }
        }
        dst[i] = '\0';
        return dst;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    char hello_str[] = "hello";
    char goodbye_str[] = "goodbye";
    char even_str[] = "even";
    char* strings[] = {hello_str, goodbye_str, even_str};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        char buf[80];

        fputs("'", stdout);
        fputs(strings[i], stdout);
        fputs("' -> '", stdout);
        fputs(reverse_strncpy(buf, strings[i], sizeof(buf)), stdout);
        fputs("' or '", stdout);
        fputs(reverse_string_inplace(strings[i]), stdout);
        fputs("'", stdout);
        fputs("\n", stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what the output for this code looks like:

```
$ ./main
'hello' -> 'olleh' or 'olleh'
'goodbye' -> 'eybdoog' or 'eybdoog'
'even' -> 'neve' or 'neve'
```

Comment: I get most of your comment but I'm having a hard time understanding point 3. Why is it bad that I called strlen a lot in the for loop?

Comment: Okay, I tried implementing all the suggestions, how does the code look now?

Comment: @DrewU I see that you made changes based on the suggestions. Your new code has issues too. I've updated my answer to reflect your changes and try and provide more assistance.

Comment: Thanks, T really like your method better. I just now understood how strings work in c better. I thought strings being in the form of arrays was only in Python. I'm redoing my code and I'll update it here...hopefully it's a lot better

Comment: Okay so I haven't really finished working on it but the latest update is where I'm at. Could it work? am I back on the issue of memory?